# How to call the parent fields in a child object in visual force pages

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, standardcontroller

Can any one help me out.Any help is very much appreciated.

I have a custom object name as "RFC__c" and it has a lookup relationship with opportunity object.Now i would like to get the opportunity fields in RFC__c object in a VF page.How to call them.I do get an Error as :

> Error: Invalid field Opportunity for SObject RFQ__c

Here is my VF Page :RFQ:

```
<apex:page Standardcontroller="RFQ__c" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" > 
 <apex:form id="RF"> 
 <h1> <apex:sectionHeader title=" SALES REQUEST FOR QUOTE FORM(RFQ)"  /> </h1> 
 <apex:pageblock >  
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="General Information">  
  <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Name}" label="Customer Name"/>  
  <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.AccountType__c}"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Date__c}"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Response_Needed_By_Date__c}"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Expected_Order_Date__c}"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.ProbabilityOf_Order_With_Requested_Price__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Comments__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection> 
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Price Request Details">  
  <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Opportunity.AccSegment__c}"/>  
  </apex:pageBlockSection> 
  </apex:pageblock> 
  </apex:form>
  </apex:page>
```

Comment: 1). Is the custom object name `RFC__c` or `RFQ__c`? 2). can you please check the WSDL for the correct relationship name?

Comment: @highfive:Custom object is : RFQ__c.

Comment: Go to **Setup > Develop > API > Generate WSDL** In the generated WSDL check the lookup relationship name for Opportunity from RFQ__c

Answer (score 2):

```
apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Opportunity.AccSegment__r}"/>
```

You need to refer the above like this

```
<apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Opportunity__r.AccSegment__c}"/>
```

Comment: @highfive,@Kiran Mutturu @ Vineeth :Thanks for your reply.It worked when i used the look up field appending with r . <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.RFQOpportunity__r.AccSegment__c}"/>

Answer (score 1):

In order to call parent fields from child object we need to use __r to call parent fields

for example ``

```
<apex:page standardController="RFQ__c">

 <apex:form >

  <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Opportunity__r.Contract_Start_Date__c}"/>

 </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Hope This helps you ..

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObj__c" recordSetVar="objs">
    <apex:pageBlock title="">
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! objs}" var="item" >
            <apex:column headerValue="Opp. Name">
                <apex:outputText value="{! item.opp_to_exp__r.Name}"/>
            </apex:column>
           </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

refer the field names with __r.fieldname of the lookup object from the source object

Comment: :Thanks for your reply : i tried in referring in different ways but i still get an Error :apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Opportunity.AccSegment__r}"/> Error: Invalid field Opportunity for SObject RFQ__c <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Opportunity__r.AccSegment__c}"/> Error: Invalid field Opportunity__r for SObject RFQ__c <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Opportunity.AccSegment__r.AccSegment__c}"/>

Comment: As  I told you replace this line <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Opportunity.AccSegment__c}"/>   with <apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Opportunity__r.AccSegment__c}"/>

Answer (score 0):

When you are accessing fields of a look up object you need to make sure you are using the correct relationship name. You can't assume the relationship name and access it like `obj.My_Lookup__c.LookupField__c`. 
 
If you are not sure about the relationship name, best way is to generating the WSDL and check the relationship name. You can generate the WSDL at ***Setup > Develop > API > Generate WSDL***

 
After generating, find for the line `<complexType name="RFQ__c">` and in the below lines you can find the  correct relationship name. Use that in the Visualforce pag.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!RFQ__c.Correct_RelationshipName__r.AccSegment__c}"/>
```